# MySQL: Select items that belong to all listed categories

Tags: mysql, select, grouping

(MySQL) 
Please help to select all items, that present in ALL categories.

```
Structure: item_category (item_id, category_id)
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
```

This query:

```
SELECT item_id FROM item_category WHERE category_id IN (1,2,3)
```

selects all item ids that belongs to categories 1 **OR** 2 **OR** 3 (returns ids 1, 2).
How should I select items that exists in categories 1 **AND** 2 **AND** 3 (to return only id 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get items having **all** categories use

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM item_category 
group by item_id 
having count(distinct category_id) = (select count(distinct category_id) 
                                      from item_category)
```

or if you know there are always those **3** `category_id`s use

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM item_category 
group by item_id 
having count(distinct category_id) = 3
```

or if you have many `category_id`s in your table but want only items having at least the categories `1,2,3` then use

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM item_category 
where category_id in (1,2,3)
group by item_id 
having count(distinct category_id) = 3
```